# Rewrite sender when relaying to provider server

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtp-auth

I am trying to relay email thru my provider that has a mail server for my domain (xxxx.com).
My postfix is configured as follows:

```
relayhost = [smtp.xxxx.com]:25
```

the server requires authorization, but it is working correctly.

```
> smtp.xxxx.com[79.96.129.xxx]:25: AUTH PLAIN AewfewfewfcewfewfewfbwBLYnNKazY1UVUjZnc=
< smtp.xxxx.com[79.96.129.xxx]:25: 235 2.7.0 User mailing+xxxx_com logged in.
```

The problem is: the relay server REQUIRES "MAIL FROM:" to be set to the same user I use for authenticaton. But the user is by default different.

```
> smtp.xxxx.com[79.96.129.xxx]:25: MAIL FROM:<user@server.xxxx.com> SIZE=296
< smtp.xxxx.com[79.96.129.xxx]:25: 550 5.1.8 Sender address rejected
```

The question is: how to make my local postfix to user "MAIL FROM:" as a user from relaying server regardless the local user that sends the mail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions. All are described in the documentation:
http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#delivering